# Combinating context:property-override and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with the followingspring context configuration file:

```
...
   <context:property-override location="classpath:query_1.properties" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations" value="classpath:query_2.properties" />
        </bean>
....
```

The problem is that the properties in the file "query_2.properties" cannot be found. The exception I get ist he following one:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException. Could not resolve placeholder...
```

Now my question: is it possible that the combination of context:property-override and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer does make no sense? Can anyone explain me in simple words what is the difference between both? Any help would be appreciated.

Thx. Horace

Answer (score 3):

Property placeholders, normally defined using a `<context:property-placeholder location=../>` resolves the placeholders in bean definitions:

for eg.

```
<bean name="myclass" class="MyClass">
    <property name="prop1" value="${prop1val}/>
</bean>
```

if the location specified with property placeholder has a property with name prop1val:

```
prop1val=aval
```

then it will be replaced in the bean `myclass`.

PrpertyOverrideConfigurer defined using `<context:property-override location="classpath:query_1.properties" />` on the other is like a push mechanism, the property is of the form `beanname.property` and it would push this property into the bean with name `beanname`.

For eg. for the above case if the location had a property of:

```
myclass.prop1=aval
```

then it would inject in `prop1` of `myclass` bean

The exception you are getting simply indicates that it is not able to find `query_2.properties` file, I doubt if it is any other configuration issue.

On which one will take effect if both are defined, I think the last one will the one to take effect.